# Best way to design class for web service calls

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have around 10 web service calls and I made the single static class where I have put all the calls in the same class

```
class WebserviceCalls {
  public static function getReportDetails($reportId) {}
  public static function getUserSession($userId) {}
  ....................................
}
```

Then I will have one proxy class `WebServiceCallProxy` which handles all the caching before actual call is made to the `WebServiceCalls` class.

With this design, as I go along and I have the new requirement that requires the new web service calls, I will simply add the new calls to the `WebServiceCalls` class.

With all this design, and as it grows, its a call for the code smell, it violates all the OOP Solid principles, class is not cohesive either. I know there has to be better way, may be some pre-defined design patterns that handles this kind of problems or breaking down each methods in simpler object and treating whole WebServiceClass as a different component.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an MVC architecture or something similar its better to split your `WebServiveCalls` and place the methods in the model layer.

Place a `getDetails()` function in your `Report` class and `getSession()` in your `User` class.

Inside those functions prepare the request parameters you need to retrieve the nessesary data. Then call a `request` function in a `WebService` class which returns the answer.

Process the response inside your methods.

If you have to add a new call you can easily add a new Model or extend an existing one. No need to modify your `WebService` class.

Comment: Makes sense but lets say if I have the User model already and I am adding the getSession which data source (property or argument) as web service whereas data source for other methods in the User model is database, how do you structure that?

Comment: Handle your `WebService` and your `Database` as services. They should only exists once in your application lifecycle. You can use singlton pattern to create an instance of them. In your `User` model `getSession` call `WebService::getInstance()->request(params)` and for a DB query use `Database::getInstance()->query(query)`
Better would be some kind of `ServiceManager` to get the service instances.

Comment: There are no "models" in MVC. Model is a layer. Please stop suggesting people patterns, that you do not understand. Also, this doen't help in any way with OP's problem. And, as cherry on top: **SINGLETONS ARE AN ANTI-PATTERN !!**

Comment: I dont suggest anyone using singleton. I suggested using a `ServiceManager`. He can choose any `creational pattern` which fits best for his needs.

Maybe you can give your solution as an answer?